# Using deriveKey on Safari

Tags: javascript, webcrypto-api

basicly i want to create a end-to-end encrypted communication on the web and was thinking about using ECDH to derive encryption keys for the data.

Using the `Web Crypto API` or better said the `SubtleCrypto` was straight farward.
But half way in I noticed that apparently Safari has implemented the `deriveKey` method, but NONE of the possible `derivedKeyAlgorithm`.
See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/deriveKey#browser_compatibility

Sadly I don't own a Apple device so i am not able to test this.

Am I missing something?
Does Safari "support" stuff that is actualy unusable?
Is there a suitable polyfill?
Is `RSA-OAEP` a good substitution?

Thank you for your answers.